# Can the Sickening Radiance spell pass through a Wall of Force?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, targeting, wall

The spell *sickening radiance* states:

> Dim, greenish light spreads within a 30-foot-radius sphere centered
>   on a point you choose within range.

*Wall of force* states:

> An invisible wall of force springs into existence at a point you choose within range.

and

> Nothing can physically pass through the wall.

As the wall is "invisible", that means it is permeable to light. So the light of sickening radiance - and thus the effect of the spell - should be allowed to pass through. But the wall also stops anything from physically passing through it; would that apply to the photons of the sickening radiance (if, indeed, "light" in D&D terms is made of photons)? If not, why can the visible spectrum of light pass but the damaging, magic light of "sickening radiance" not?